# What will happen when taps at secondary side of auto-transformer are connected together (short-circuited)?

Tags: transformer, protection, short-circuit, winding, autotransformer

In case of Auto-transformer, there is only one winding, having three lead wires (1 for primary/input, 1 for secondary/output, and 1 common between both). At the secondary side (the output side), there are taps (sort of voltage dividers).

I have a auto-transformer with input at 220 V, and i have taps at the secondary side at 200 V and 240 V (only mentioning my required taps, there are many).

My question is, what will happen if the taps at the secondary get short-circuited (200 V tap and 240 V tap gets short)?
What will be the effect of this incidence on primary voltage and secondary voltage?
Will transformer be okay? it won't get damage or something??

Comment: Bad things happen. Possibly very bad things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a short circuit across a portion of the winding of an autotransformer, that portion of the winding will pass excessive current, and may be damaged - just as if you had shorted turns in either winding of a normal transformer.

Comment: @BetaEngineer please refrain from restating the content of an answer as a question. Your comment is clearly answered in the answer itself.